# Is Aftersave() callback with $created parameter works on CakePHP 1.1?

Tags: cakephp

I am working on a CakePHP 1.1 project. I know it is a really old version of the framework but it is not my project.

I try to get the `$created` variable in my `afterSave()` callback :

```
function afterSave($created) {
      debug($created);
}
```

According to the [2.x documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/fr/models/callback-methods.html#aftersave), `$created` should be `true` or `false`.

In my case, `$created` is not defined.

> Notice: Undefined variable: created in /app/models/property.php on line 370

Am I missing something ?
I am having a lot of trouble for finding documentations/informations on the version 1.1 of the framework.

Is this even possible in CakePHP 1.1 ? If not, what alternative can I use ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [CakePHP 1.1 documentation](http://api11.cakephp.org/class_model.html#b188f5378b4bb7f0b0513ab2dd905bdc) there are no parameters for `afterSave()`. It looks like the `$created` parameter was [introduced in CakePHP 1.2](http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html#aftersave).

If your records have `created` and `modified` fields you could check if these match (*i.e.* is a new record):-

```
function afterSave($created) {
    if ($this->data[$this->alias]['created'] === $this->data[$this->alias]['modified']) {
        // created
    }
}
```

Not sure if my code example is a 100% correct as it is a very long time since I worked with CakePHP 1.x, but will hopefully put you on the right track. There may (probably) be better solutions than this.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed you are right, I arrived to the same conclusion and used a similar condition : `if(!isset($this->data[$this->name]['id']))` because when it is created no `id` is present in `$this->data`. Your solution is also perfectly working thank you very much!